# Updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and Wi-Fi is now very weak - RTL8723BE

Tags: networking, wireless, 18.04, lenovo, realtek-wireless

I just updated to Ubuntu 18.04 and my Wi-Fi stopped working on my Lenovo Laptop.
Wi-Fi itself is still working for other systems, but my laptop can only connect once I'm next to my router. Seems the signal is too weak, but this makes no sense as all other devices (smartphone,TV) work with greater distance.

Do you have any idea?

```
:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]  
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b728]  
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be  
    Kernel modules: rtl8723be  
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: yes  
    Hard blocked: no  
2: hci0: Bluetooth  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no  
3: phy0: Wireless LAN  
    Soft blocked: no  
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Yep, problem is solved. Linked thread helped. Thanks!